# Signature manifestations- Add Date and Time with the sign image

Tags: php, docusignapi

I want to implement the below in DocuSign using embedded signing:

Section 11.50(a) requires that signature manifestations have the printed name of the signer, the date and time the signature was executed and the reason for signing.

DocuSign provides this information at each signature location below the signer’s signature image, as shown below.

[image: 1]

Comment: @InbarGazit Can you please help me to use date and time info below the sign image as shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the image you have above is of a Digital Signature not Electronic Signature. You would have to talk to your DocuSign Sales Person to get this feature for your account (or your Customer Support) and then when you use digital signature - you should see the above.

Comment: Yes, i have talked with docusign team and now my problem has been solved.